# .htaccess - mod_rewrite is working for some pages but not for others

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am stuck into a weird problem.

I have a file at the location **/public_html/academics/courses.php**

I want .htaccess to mod_rewrite the URLs as below:

Original URL: **http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/courses/**

After mod_rewrite: **http://niecdelhi.ac.in/index.php?inc=/academics/courses/**

What I want, basically, is to mod_rewrite all URLs to index.php and pass the URL as a parameter named "inc". Then, in the index.php I include the file by doing include($_GET['inc']);

mod_rewrite is working for some pages on the website. and I am getting the URL in $inc. But, it is not working at all for other pages.

For example, consider the two files that exist on the server:

1. **http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/courses.php**
2. **http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/library.php**

mod_rewrite is working for the first, the file gets included in index.php
But for the second I get the plain existing file. not the one included in index.php

I hope you understand the problem that I am facing. Please provide me with the solution.

**.htaccess file**

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?inc=$1&%1 [L]
```

Page working: http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/courses/

Page not working: http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/library/

## ****EDIT****

There is no other .htaccess anywhere. Although, I have found a clue about what is happening. The problem is happening only in Linux server. The code is working correctly in Windows server.I have a Linux server with PHP 5.2.16.

Also, regarding some pages working and some not. I have found that only those pages are working which have a folder with identical name in the same directory. For example, The **academics directory** is as below:

```
academics/
    |_ courses/
    |    |_ mba.php
    |    |_ mca.php
    |_ courses.php
    |_ library.php
```

Now, Since courses.php has a folder with identical name in same directory. It gets mod_rewrite fine. But library.php is not getting mod_rewrite.

Linux server is skipping the mod_rewrite for the files that actually exist. Why so ??

Comment: Are the other two files below the htaccess file in the file tree?

Comment: And are you sure that your links point to the correct address with the query string added? And not the relative path?

Comment: @NVTOnline - yes these files are below the same .htaccess in file tree..

Answer (score 0):

My only guess is that there is another .htaccess somewhere in your structure (most obviously inside /academics/ ) that is overriding the rule for "library".

Could there be another mod_rewriting rule inside that folder that is kicking in for the word LIBRARY and probably messing up your rewriting.

Note that it might also be a native apache issue. For example, in ubuntu, by default in version 10.10 (i think thats it) if you had a /javascript/ folder, it would be short circuited to /usr/lib/javascript or something like that...

Check all possible instances of mod rewrite in httpd.conf, all dynamicaly loaded .conf files, your vhost file and finaly the path of your document root...

Comment: There is no other .htaccess anywhere else... I have found some clues about the problem....Please read the edited part of the question.. Thanks...

Comment: If you have only php files that you want affected by this rule, why not simply do: RewriteRule ^(.*.php) index.php?inc=$1 [L] this usually rewrites the file but your $_GET will still be filled with the content requested earlier... Try it out and tell me if it works...

Comment: Thanks for reply, The code u have suggested is good but I want to rewrite all the below URLs: –
`
    http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/library.php

    http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/library
    
    http://niecdelhi.ac.in/academics/library/
`
 to **index.php?inc=/academics/library**

Comment: I honestly got right the same issue this morning, when I uploaded a site on the linux server of Aruba.it. all the pages are from on template, but in some case it works, another cases not. I thought it was my .htaccess file that, btw, it was working excellently on the same site when it was on a server of the previous provider. Thus I suppose it belongs to Apache's settings but not clue which one